# Compare two array of objects and return matching values in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, reduce, intersection

I have two arrays of objects: `inputData` and `jobList`. I have to compare the primarySkills array of both the array of objects and return only those values which are matching in both the array.My array of objects are as below:

```js
let inputData = [
    {
        "candidateID": "911772331",
        "skillSet": ["Information Technology"],
        "addressCity": "Bengaluru",
        "addressState": "KA",
        "country": "India",
        "primarySkills": ['asp.net', 'react', 'javascript'],
        "secondarySkills": ['powerbi', 'redux'],
        "preferredPositionType": [],
    }
]

let jobList = [
  {
    jobId: '600039355',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: [ 'asp.net','node' ],
    secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
    skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
    Address: 'Indonesia, Bekasi Kabupaten, 53, Jalan Londan 5',
    City: 'Bekasi Kabupaten',
    State: 'JABODETABEK',
    Zipcode: '17522',
    Country: 'Indonesia'
  },
  {
    jobId: '562190375',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: [ 'javascript','mainframe' ],
    secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
    skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
    Address: 'India, Pune, 411001, Pune, Pune Station',
    City: 'Pune',
    State: 'MH',
    Zipcode: '411001',
    Country: 'India'
  },
  {
    jobId: '883826845',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: [ 'sqlserver', 'react', 'powershell' ],
    secondarySkills: [ 'powerbi' ],
    skillSet: [ 'powerbi' ],
    Address: 'ประเทศไทย, หมู่ที่ 3, 1234',
    City: 'หมู่ที่ 3',
    State: null,
    Zipcode: '57110',
    Country: 'ประเทศไทย'
  }
]
```

I have done the below mentioned code to achieve this:

```js
jobList.forEach((item) => {
  inputData.forEach((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= item.primarySkills.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= data.primarySkills.length; j++) {
        if (item.primarySkills[i] === data.primarySkills[j]) {
          PMSkill.push(item.primarySkills[i]);
        } else {                                    
          PMSkill.push(0)
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
Expected output to be like in the PMSkill array:
let PMSkill= [
  {
    jobId: '600039355',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: [ 'asp.net'],----here asp.net is the only skill matching with inputData primarySkill
    secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
    skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
    Address: 'Indonesia, Bekasi Kabupaten, 53, Jalan Londan 5',
    City: 'Bekasi Kabupaten',
    State: 'JABODETABEK',
    Zipcode: '17522',
    Country: 'Indonesia'
  },
  {
    jobId: '562190375',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: [ 'javascript'],
    secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
    skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
    Address: 'India, Pune, 411001, Pune, Pune Station',
    City: 'Pune',
    State: 'MH',
    Zipcode: '411001',
    Country: 'India'
  },
  {
    jobId: '883826845',
    jobType: 'fulltime',
    primarySkills: ['react'],
    secondarySkills: [ 'powerbi' ],
    skillSet: [ 'powerbi' ],
    Address: 'ประเทศไทย, หมู่ที่ 3, 1234',
    City: 'หมู่ที่ 3',
    State: null,
    Zipcode: '57110',
    Country: 'ประเทศไทย'
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your code not work? If so - what happens and what should happen instead? If the code doesn't work, then what do you need help with?

Comment: Yes the code doesn't work.Currently what happens is the PMSkill array gives wrong or blank values. What is expected is primarySkills field of both array of objects should be comapred and should return common values in PMSkill array.

Comment: @tanu ... the OP usually also describes the expected result/output.

Comment: Sorry this is my first @ this platform,so missed it. The expected output should be ['javascript'] when inputData is compared with JobList for first time. Printing the common value in both the array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getIntersection(x, y) {
  // ensure two arrays ...
  const [
    comparisonBase, // ... the shorter one as comparison base
    comparisonList, // ... the longer one to filter from.
  ] = [[...x], [...y]]
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

  // create a `Map` based lookup table from the shorter array.
  const itemLookup = comparisonBase
    .reduce((map, item) => map.set(item, true), new Map)

  // the intersection is the result of following filter task.
  return comparisonList.filter(item => itemLookup.has(item));
}

const inputData = [{
  "candidateID": "911772331",
  "skillSet": ["Information Technology"],
  "addressCity": "Bengaluru",
  "addressState": "KA",
  "country": "India",
  "primarySkills": ['asp.net', 'react', 'javascript'],
  "secondarySkills": ['powerbi', 'redux'],
  "preferredPositionType": [],
}];
const jobList = [{
  jobId: '600039355',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
  Address: 'Indonesia, Bekasi Kabupaten, 53, Jalan Londan 5',
  City: 'Bekasi Kabupaten',
  State: 'JABODETABEK',
  Zipcode: '17522',
  Country: 'Indonesia'
}, {
  jobId: '562190375',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
  Address: 'India, Pune, 411001, Pune, Pune Station',
  City: 'Pune',
  State: 'MH',
  Zipcode: '411001',
  Country: 'India'
}, {
  jobId: '883826845',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'sqlserver', 'azure', 'powershell' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'powerbi' ],
  skillSet: [ 'powerbi' ],
  Address: 'ประเทศไทย, หมู่ที่ 3, 1234',
  City: 'หมู่ที่ 3',
  State: null,
  Zipcode: '57110',
  Country: 'ประเทศไทย'
}];

const candidateSkills = inputData[0].primarySkills;
const openJobsSkills = [...new Set(
  jobList.reduce((arr, { primarySkills }) => arr.concat(primarySkills), [])
)];

const skillIntersection = getIntersection(openJobsSkills, candidateSkills);

console.log({ candidateSkills, openJobsSkills, skillIntersection });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** according to the OP's more detailed further request*

> *"I want to compare the `inputData.primarySkills` one by one with each list of objects in `jobList` and update the matching skills against the `primarySkills` field of `jobList`."*

In this case one needs a task which `forEach` item of `jobList` reassigns it's `primarySkills` property value with the property specific intersection with the base `primarySkills` array taken from `inputData`.

The provided solution makes use of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and its [2nd `thisArg` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description) in order to decouple the functionality from outside scope references/dependencies.

Depending on whether one needs to leave `jobList` un-mutated/untouched, on might be in need of an additional mapping task which has to create a deep clone of each `jobList` item.

```js
function getIntersection(x, y) {
  // ensure two arrays ...
  const [
    comparisonBase, // ... the shorter one as comparison base
    comparisonList, // ... the longer one to filter from.
  ] = [[...x], [...y]]
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

  // create a `Map` based lookup table from the shorter array.
  const itemLookup = comparisonBase
    .reduce((map, item) => map.set(item, true), new Map)

  // the intersection is the result of following filter task.
  return comparisonList.filter(item => itemLookup.has(item));
}

const inputData = [{
  "candidateID": "911772331",
  "skillSet": ["Information Technology"],
  "addressCity": "Bengaluru",
  "addressState": "KA",
  "country": "India",
  "primarySkills": ['asp.net', 'react', 'javascript'],
  "secondarySkills": ['powerbi', 'redux'],
  "preferredPositionType": [],
}];

const jobList = [{
  jobId: '600039355',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'asp.net','node' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
  Address: 'Indonesia, Bekasi Kabupaten, 53, Jalan Londan 5',
  City: 'Bekasi Kabupaten',
  State: 'JABODETABEK',
  Zipcode: '17522',
  Country: 'Indonesia'
}, {
  jobId: '562190375',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'javascript','mainframe' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'javascript' ],
  skillSet: [ 'javascript' ],
  Address: 'India, Pune, 411001, Pune, Pune Station',
  City: 'Pune',
  State: 'MH',
  Zipcode: '411001',
  Country: 'India'
}, {
  jobId: '883826845',
  jobType: 'fulltime',
  primarySkills: [ 'sqlserver', 'react', 'powershell' ],
  secondarySkills: [ 'powerbi' ],
  skillSet: [ 'powerbi' ],
  Address: 'ประเทศไทย, หมู่ที่ 3, 1234',
  City: 'หมู่ที่ 3',
  State: null,
  Zipcode: '57110',
  Country: 'ประเทศไทย'
}];

function updatePrimarySkillsWithIntersectionOfBoundBaseSkills(jobItem) {
  const basePrimarySkills = this;

  jobItem.primarySkills =
    getIntersection(jobItem.primarySkills, basePrimarySkills);
}

// if needed ... create new array with real `jobItem` clones ...
const pmSkillList = jobList.map(jobItem =>
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jobItem))
);
// ... otherwise (`jobList.forEach`) ... just ...

// .... reassign the item specific `primarySkills` property value.
pmSkillList.forEach(
  // the callback
  updatePrimarySkillsWithIntersectionOfBoundBaseSkills,
  // the 2nd `thisArg` argument
  inputData[0].primarySkills,
);

// log any involved data.
console.log({ inputData, jobList, pmSkillList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Seliger for answering my query. Can you please help me with one more scenarion (i have also updated the expected output above in my code snippet). I want to comapre the inputdata[primarySkills] one by one with each list of objects in jobList and update the matching skills against the primarySkills field of jobList.

Comment: Can you please help me @Peter Seliger with the above explained scenario

Comment: @tanu ... done.

Comment: Thank you soo soo much @Peter Seliger. This was really helpful and very kind of you to answer my query once again.Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a simple method for that I use a lot

```
function arr_intersection(a1: number[], a2: number[]) {
  return a1.filter((x) => a2.includes(x));
}
```

you can also use the intersection method in lodash

```
const _ = require("lodash");
  
// Original array
let array1 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4]
let array2 = [2, 4, 5, 6]
let array3 = [2, 3, 5, 6]
  
// Using _.intersection() method
let newArray = _.intersection(
        array1, array2, array3);
  
// Printing original Array
console.log("original Array1: ", array1)
console.log("original Array2: ", array2)
console.log("original Array3: ", array3)
  
// Printing the newArray
console.log("new Array: ", newArray)
```

here you can send multiple array not like my method

Answer (score 0):

Change your verification like so

```js
matchingPrimarySkills = []

jobList.forEach((job) => {
  inputData.forEach((candidate) => {
    job.primarySkills.forEach( (jobPrimarySkill) => {
       candidate.primarySkills.forEach( (candidatePrimarySkill) => {
        if (jobPrimarySkill === candidatePrimarySkill &&  matchingPrimarySkills.indexOf(jobPrimarySkill) === -1) {
          matchingPrimarySkills.push(jobPrimarySkill)
        }
      })
    })
  })
})

// With your examples, it will og [ "javascript"] without duplicates
console.log(matchingPrimarySkills)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve the desired output. Only the relevant properties are shown just for demo. You can pass candidates from the `inputData` to the `getJobs(input)` function to get list of jobs matching some `primarySkills` from input:

```js
let inputData = [
  { candidateID: '111111', primarySkills: ['asp.net', 'react', 'javascript'] },
  { candidateID: '222222', primarySkills: ['python'] },
  { candidateID: '333333', primarySkills: ['powershell', 'node'] },
]

let jobList = [
  { jobId: '77777', primarySkills: ['asp.net', 'node'] },
  { jobId: '88888', primarySkills: ['javascript', 'python'] },
  { jobId: '99999', primarySkills: ['sqlserver', 'azure', 'powershell'] },
]

function getJobs(input) {
  // Get a copy of jopList
  const temp = jobList.map(obj => { return { ...obj } })

  return temp.filter(job => {
    // Filter the job's primarySkills to only show
    // skills matching the candidates's primarySkills.
    job.primarySkills = job.primarySkills.filter(jobSkill =>
      input.primarySkills.includes(jobSkill)
    )
    return job.primarySkills.length
  })
}

// Get jobs for all candidates in inputData
for (let candidate of inputData) {
  console.log(`\nJobs for candidateID ${candidate.candidateID}:\n`, getJobs(candidate))
}
```